# Command Line Virus Scan with Output

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, file-upload, antivirus

What is the best tool to handle doing a command line virus scan in C#? I am looking to allow users to upload files to my site, but I want to scan their files for viruses and if one is found, to get the output of the result so I can suspend the user's account automatically.

Any tutorials, guides, or tools that are recommended for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this pretty easily using ClamWin with the following argument:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ClamWin\bin\clamscan.exe -d C:\ProgramData\.clamwin\db --remove --stdout MY_FILE_NAME_AND_PATH
```

This allows me to read the StOut from my C# code and parse it and it also removes the file if a virus exists.

Answer (score 4):

OPSWAT has a Antivirus Integration SDK here - (http://www.opswat.com/antivirussdk_client.shtml)

Sophos provides a command line interface to scan viruses - (http://www.sophos.com/support/knowledgebase/article/13252.html)

You can explore using these directly or handle it asynchronously as a queued job.

Answer (score 0):

Security Essentials has a [command-line interface](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_scanning/does-mse-have-the-ability-to-scan-from-the-command/809b0b84-9396-49b2-95c4-68e7ec539fc7). From what I can tell, it's closely related to ForeFront (enterprise use) and it probably has the same thing.